# use dynamic reconfigure with arrays

Tags: dynamic-reconfigure

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I want to use dynamic reconfiguration to modify an array in a ROS node, but I didn't found any example of how to modify the .cfg file on the web.

I want this line: gen.add("int_param",    int_t,    0, "An Integer parameter", 50,  0, 100)

in something kind of: gen.add("int_array",    int_t[2],    0, "An Integer array", [50 20],  [0 0], [100 100])

Can someone help?
Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/213855/use-dynamic-reconfigure-with-arrays/) by [TheBoris](https://answers.ros.org/users/23212/theboris/) on ROS Answers with karma: 35 on 2015-07-16

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

According to [this Tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/dynamic_reconfigure/Tutorials/HowToWriteYourFirstCfgFile), arrays are not allowed:

> **type** - defines the type of value stored, and can be any of int_t, double_t, str_t, or bool_t

Maybe you can achieve what you want by using the `group` type.

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2015-07-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [TheBoris](https://answers.ros.org/users/23212/theboris/) on 2015-07-16**:
Sorry, but i'm a newbie, what is a group type?

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2015-07-16**:
See the [following tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/dynamic_reconfigure/Tutorials/SettingUpDynamicReconfigureForANode). Maybe this gives you a hint.